# constraint layout textview not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm creating a simple recycler view item layout with an image and textview inside a constraint layout. I'm setting constraint for image to be on the left side and text starts from the right of the image and to the end of the parent. However, when I do the text view is not shown on the screen. Can someone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_character_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="Homer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img_character_photo"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_character_photo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

[image]

And If I remove the app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" from textView the I get following result.
[image]

Comment: please check the text color - I guess it's white (your layout looks good in my sample app). BTW [LayoutInspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) is a great tool if your Views don't show up like they should

Comment: @0X0nosugar text shows up when i remove app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" constraint but the text goes out of bounds on the right side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to connect at least one point in both the axis for each view when using `ConstraintLayout` i.e. you should connect at least one point vertically and one point horizontally to get it right. Also, if you read about how to use `ConstraintLayout` properly, it tells the same. I believe this would solve your problem (and you would also see all your views on the actual device).

**Do something like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_character_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="Homer Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
        Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img_character_photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_character_photo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="5dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Screenshot (of the above code):**

*For screen size - 7.0 inch (1200 x 1920 pixels)  [Device: Nexus 7]*

[image]

For more information, please go through:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#7

I hope, this helps you.

Comment: can you give an example if you don't mind @Nitin. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, try connecting the ImageView's start to the start of the parent and its top to the top of the parent and the TextView's start to the end of the ImageView + its top to the top of the parent and its end to the end of the parent (as that's one of your desired condition). Rest all points are for basic connectivity so that all the views appear when you run it in a actual device.

Comment: added those 5 constraints. I still get the same result.

Comment: Can you please tell me your ConstraintLayout's dependency version?

Comment: it's using the latest one 1.1.3

Comment: Can you please clean, rebuild and sync your overall project once?

Comment: Okay, then. I don't see such error when I am running it in my Android Studio. Still, let me check.

Comment: by adding those 5 constraints i get to see the text but it goes out of bounds from the right. But then I from layout_width of textView from 0 to match_parent. It is showing fine but now the text is behind the image view.

Comment: For that, simply put the TextView's code after the ImageView's code and then try to give some suitable padding and margin.

Comment: I guess that fixes the problem for now. Thank you

Comment: For me, its working absolutely fine on various screen sizes (with dependency version 1.0.2). I hope you would up-vote my answer as well as mark it as the best.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Abhi.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing

```
android:maxLines="2"
```

attribute from textView element

Layout code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_character_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Homer Test SHOW Homer Test SHOW Homer TestSHOWHomer Test SHOW Homer Test SHOW Homer Test SHOW END"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img_character_photo"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_character_photo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@color/colorAccent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />
```

Comment: Sure? It works in my case... It's limiting number of lines to 2, and since there is much more text it shows it out of the screen... removing this attribute from textview element should display all text on screen but in much more lines.

Comment: yes, it made the item view much bigger but no text was shown. I tried removing the parentEnd constraint from the textView. It should all the text however it was still going out of bounds from the right side. Can you post your code if you don't mind. Thanks

Comment: Try and replace: tools:text="Homer"  With: android:text="Homer"...How do you set text in textview?

Comment: the text is set in the recycler view adapter class. tools:text is just a place holder to see in the xml.

Comment: Didn't see you asking my code, sorry... I'm posting now.

Comment: Not sure what's the problem, whatever I try it works. at first I didn't see text until I replaced tools:text with android:text, and removing android:maxLines="2" so that it can put all text on screen. If changing these 2 things don't help, sorry

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the RecyclerView was inflated by an adapter and the adapter had correct constraints and 0dp width. However, it still didn't work.

What I ended up doing was changing the layout_width of the RecyclerView element to match_parent, rather than wrap_content.

**RecyclerView**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/stepsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

**Adapter.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/steps"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stepsImg"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stepsText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/stepsIma"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```